TV Show/Movie that has Bill Nye and a wormhole!
All I remember is that it's either a TV show episode or a movie that has main characters who are going to a science convention where only the top scientist attend. This is when Bill Nye steps in as a guest star. The convention is being held by a rich guy who decides to unveil a wormhole machine and it eventually goes haywire and everything starts to spontaneously freeze. That's all I remember. I know I'm not thinking about his show 'Bill Nye the Science Guy'. Please help.

You seem to be after the Stargate: Atlantis episode Brain Storm from 2008 (Season 5, Episode 16).

Rodney finally invites Jennifer on a date; to attend a science conference with him. But petty jealousies arise at the conference that have to be suppressed when a proposed solution for global warming has potentially lethal side effects.

Bill Nye is in attendance as is Neil deGrasse Tyson (as themselves) when the malfunctioning machine (a matter bridge channeling heat into an alternate reality) starts freezing everything. Here's a clip:



